Using Anchor 26 and lower with Ubuntu 22 or newer
Anchor versions 28 and above build fine on Ubuntu 22 LTS. However, some of our programs are old and still require maintenance with older versions of Anchor.
Anchor 26 and below, built with avm install 0.26.0 fail because of an older version of openssl: error: failed to run custom build command for openssl-sys v0.9.77
The easiest approach is just to head the libssl archive (http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/), pick an old version, and downgrade. But that's also a bad idea, because the version used in 0.26.0 and earlier is very old.
How can I get avm install 0.26.0 to succeed without downgrading the system's libssl version?

It seems to suffice (in the sense than Anchor 26 will build) to install the latest version of libssl-dev as of June 2024:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config libssl-dev

